# Suggestion for getting a type of plot

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am planning to use python to get a plot like this [image].

But, I am only able to get this, [image]

So, I would appreciate it if someone helps me with these issues,
(Maybe how to format the data)

1. How to have lower X-axis values highlighted like in the original plot
2. Also, how to add the info to the legends.
   Please check the code below and looking forward to your suggestions.
   Numpy and Matplotlib are being used.

   ```
   x = [192, 188/4, 168/24, 144/48, 96/96]
   ys = [[2.20, 0.758, 0.691], [1.44, 0.708, 0.733], [0.491, 0.379, 0.440], [0.349, 0.350, 0.165], [0.199, 0.157, 0.163]]

   print(len(x), len(ys))
   colors = [["r", "y", "g"], ["r", "y", "g"], ["r", "y", "g"], ["r", "y", "g"], ["r", "y", "g"]]
   print(colors)

   for y, x, c in zip(ys, x, colors):
   #     print(y, [x])
   #     print([x]*len(y))
       plt.scatter([x]*len(y), y, color = c)    


   plt.xticks([192, 188/4, 168/24, 144/48, 96/96])
   plt.xlabel("Si/Al Ratio")
   plt.ylabel("Diff Coeff (Ang**2)")
   # plt.legend(['Water_Cubic{}'.format(i) for i in [12, 24, 48]], loc=2, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), borderaxespad=0., fontsize=11)
   plt.title("Si/Al vs Diff Coeff at 300k for Water Content (12, 24, 48)")
   ```

Comment: There a quite a few issues with your code logic. One issue is you are shadowing your domain `x` with the local `x` in the for loop. Add some debug or print statements in your code to track what you are actually passing to your plot function, and compare that to what you expect it to be. That part we can't tell you, it's your data.

Comment: Drop the xticks command, so that you will get a proper set of axis labels.
Use `plt.errorbar` so that you can specify the error bars in the plot. Look at the documentation for that, in particular the 'marker' keyword for getting the triangles etc.
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html

Answer (score 1):

Charged you code a bit to hopefully get you closer:

```
import numpy as np

X = [192, 188/4, 168/24, 144/48, 96/96]
Ys = [[2.20, 0.758, 0.691], [1.44, 0.708, 0.733], [0.491, 0.379, 0.440], [0.349, 0.350, 0.165], [0.199, 0.157, 0.163]]
colors = ['r','y','g']

# convert to 2D numpy array
Ys_ = np.asarray(Ys).T

for i, y in enumerate(Ys_):
    plt.scatter(X, y, color=colors[i])    


plt.xticks([192, 188/4, 168/24, 144/48, 96/96])
plt.xlabel("Si/Al Ratio")
plt.ylabel("Diff Coeff (Ang**2)")
# plt.legend(['Water_Cubic{}'.format(i) for i in [12, 24, 48]], loc=2, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), borderaxespad=0., fontsize=11)
plt.title("Si/Al vs Diff Coeff at 300k for Water Content (12, 24, 48)")
```

[image]